# Faulty convergence of Conv Neural Network for vector determination (Loss function)

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

**Problem:** Given some data the CNN will output a vector of length 2, representing some kind of motion.

However, when using the RMSE or MAE as the loss function, I noticed that the neural network will converge to [0,0] vector, because on average that will yield the lowest error, due to the training  data having a wide variety of magnitude and directions.

How could I avoid this faulty convergence?

As a perhaps reformulation: I want to know how I could create a loss function that punishes the neural network for taking the simple solution of [0,0]

Comment: To me, "will converge to [0,0] ... due to the training data having a wide variety of magnitude and directions" sounds like a non sequitur. Surely, the wide variety alone isn't the problem?

Comment: Do you have any other idea of what could be causing the convergence to [0,0]? I have experimented by changing the training data to a very limited set of directions and the error did not persist ex: 0-45 degrees relative to the horizontal

Comment: It's really hard to say without more details about your problem, the inputs, the network architecture and the training/test sets. For example, it could just be that the inputs are simply not good predictors of the outputs.

Comment: As a perhaps reformulation: I want to know how I could create a loss function that punishes the neural network for taking the simple solution of [0,0]